# Tigela, prato fundo, prato de sopa: qual é a diferença? Como distinguir?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Há alguma diferença entre *tigelas*, *pratos fundos*, e *pratos de sopa*? Há pratos que são também tigelas? Há tigelas que não são pratos, ou pratos fundos que não são tigelas?

Quando encontro uma peça de loiça, bastante fundo para servir como recipiente de sopa, como é que posso saber se é tigela ou prato?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em relação a tigela/prato de sopa:

- Uma [tigela](https://www.flickr.com/photos/gamany/2823324197) (*bowl*) não tem bordas onde a concavidade diminui significativamente ou mesmo se anula, um [prato de sopa](http://www.leiliane.com.br/caldos-e-sopas/sopa-de-frango-desfiado/) geralmente tem-nas.
- Para o mesmo volume, uma tigela é mais alta e um prato de sopa é mais largo e chato. A base de uma tigela é mais pequena. Consequentemente, uma tigela tem uma área de superfície mais pequena e a comida arrefece mais lentamente.
- Um prato de sopa usa-se para comer principalmente sopa. Uma tigela não é geralmente usada para comer sopa; é tipicamente utilizada para fins mais nobres, como cereais com leite.
- Devido à forma, uma tigela pode agarrar-se e levar à boca, um prato de sopa é mais difícil.
- Ambos são geralmente de louça, mas as tigelas aparecem com mais frequência feitas de barro ou de plástico.

Um prato fundo é apenas o que o nome indica; não creio que seja um termo da arte. Portanto um prato semelhante a um prato de sopa (mas com mais frequência sem bordas), mas destinado a comida que tenha muito molho, como arroz de tamboril ou ensopados.

Comment: Discordo: o fim nobre das tigelas é servir caldo verde. Agora leite com cereais!

Answer (score 3):

### Antigamente era tudo muito simples:

[image]

### Mas agora a vida é muito mais complicada:

[image]

Comment: Piadola: essas duas primeiras imagens não são antes malgas??

Comment: @ANeves As duas primeiras de cima? *Malga* para mim é a mesma coisa que tigela. O DACL diz que é uma tigela em forma de calota esférica. Para ti são coisas diferentes?

Comment: Não, são a mesma coisa. Essa é a piada. :p